# Can i have nice password input screen for encrypted disk like in Mint but on Debian?

Tags: linux, boot, debian, passwords, disk-encryption

On Linux Mint, when one boots up the machine with encrypted disk, nice graphical screen pops up with password input. Debian, on the other hand, display bunch of text in text mode and asks for the password in text mode. Well, I like Mint's screen much, much better than Debian's text mode. Is it possible to (how?) setup something similar on Debian box? And I mean no password for sessions, but for password of the encrypted disk, just next instant after the boot.

Comment: On Mint, is the main system disk encrypted? (And how, LUKS?) Or just some extra/data disks or partitions?

Comment: Whole disk, yes. Is it LUKS? I don't know --- it's what Mints (18.3) offered during installation. On the second though: there are several disks, but only one (the encrypted one) is for Mint. Others are NTFS and other filesystems (which Mint can mount). Mint disk has two partitions: swap and all the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, Mint uses [Plymouth](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/) for its graphical boot screen, including password prompts. This is the most common graphical boot software on Linux.

Plymouth is [available](https://wiki.debian.org/plymouth) on Debian, although whether it integrates well with the Debian initramfs – or just barely – is another topic. However, you can try following Ubuntu-specific documentation.

Comment: This https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225858/is-there-a-way-to-enter-a-password-with-onscreen-keyboard-to-unlock-a-luks-crypt#259269 might be relevant

Comment: check for plymouth-ask-password.target on your system it should be enabled to allow the desired effect, but as @grawity mentioned it is a crap shoot how well it will work without massaging.